# HTML Input Forms not displaying entire placeholder text; but includes the quote marks

Tags: html, forms, input, placeholder

I am writing a simple input form, with most of the text inputs set to have some placeholder text.

For whatever reason, only the first contiguous text string of the placeholder text displays. The quotation marks also display. I am trying to figure out why that is, and make the necessary changes (encoding? escape characters? my markup is just idiotically terrible?)

I'm sure it's something simple. I'm sure it's something ridiculous. I apologize in advance.

Here is my code. Thanks, to anyone with any ideas.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" class="layout-signup " >
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Feline Friends is a foster-based, no kill, cat rescue organization serving Chicago.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="feline, friends, online, cat, animal, shelter, pet, rescue, foster, volunteer, Chicago, Illinois">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Sign up  - Feline Friends">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.felinefriendschicago.org/fosterapply.html">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Feline Friends is a foster-based, no kill, cat rescue organization serving Chicago.">
  <title>Sign Up – Feline Friends</title>

      <link rel="icon" href="file:///Users/lieselhess/Documents/favicon.ico">
      <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///Users/lieselhess/Documents/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->


      <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.felinefriendschicago.org/fosterapply.html">

      <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///Users/lieselhess/Documents/reboot.css" media="all"> -->


  </head>

  <p>
  You can request printable foster application forms by email from Toni McNaughton at         <a href="mailto:tonimcn@rcn.com?Subject=Foster%20Application%20Request" target="_top">tonimcn@rcn.com</a> or Lisa Ward at <a href="mailto:catladychicago@yahoo.com?Subject=Foster%20Application%20Request" target="_top">catladychicago@yahoo.com</a>
</p>

<strong class="line-thru">or</strong>
<p>


    </div>
  </form>
</section>

<section class="register">
  <div class="content">

    <h2 class="center hdr-l">
Apply for our foster program below:    </h2>

<form id=fosterapp>
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Details</legend>
<ol>
<li>
<label for=name>Name</label>
<input id=name name=name type=text placeholder=”First and Last Name” required autofocus>
</li>
<li>
<label for=email>Email</label>
<input id=email name=email type=email placeholder=”example@domain.com” required>
</li>
<li>
<label for=homephone>Home Phone</label>
<input id=homephone name=homephone type=tel placeholder=”Eg. +7735551212” required>
</li>
<li>
<label for=workphone>Work Phone</label>
<input id=workphone name=workphone type=tel placeholder=”Eg. +7735551212”>
<input id=callwork name=qcallwork type=radio>
<label for=callwork>I may receive calls at work</label>
<input id=nocallwork name=qcallwork type=radio>
<label for=nocallwork>I may NOT receive calls at work</label>
</li>

</li>
<li>
<label for=address>Address</label>
<textarea id=address name=address rows=5 required></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Household Information</legend>
<ol>
<li>
</ol>
</li>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your quotation marks look wierd on the input attributes.  They should look like the ones around class="line-through".

Comment: @circusdei -- YES. THANK YOU. Typing the double quotes character in my text editor (Libre Office for Mac) automatically inserts these terrible quotes that I'm sure someone at some point thought were "prettier". I already ditched TextEdit for similar but unrelated issues. Is there any decent text editor for writing HTML on OS X?

Comment: I like Notepad++, but I think it's only for windows.

Comment: @MonkeyMoose — Many. Just make sure it is a text editor instead of a word processor. Sublime, Komodo, BBEdit, Emacs, GVim, TextMate, Eclipse, the list is huge.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You're the best. This has been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your issue and now there are visible all placeholders.
Check this: http://cssdesk.com/PWNzt

I think that the issue was there that you used ” insetead of "